# ASP.NET, Gridview and Linqdatasource generates error on update

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework-4

Sample

```
<asp:GridView ID="data_basic_addresses" runat="server" AllowPaging="False" BorderWidth="0" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="AddressId" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
DataSourceID="LinqAddressDS" PageSize="20" CssClass="GridViewClass">
<Columns>
   <asp:BoundField DataField="AddressId" HeaderText="AddressId" SortExpression="AddressId" ReadOnly="True"/>
   <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Street" SortExpression="Address"  />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City"  />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="State" HeaderText="State" SortExpression="State"  />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="Zip" HeaderText="Zip" SortExpression="Zip"  />
   <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Options" ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqAddressDS" runat="server" OnContextCreating="LinqDS_ContextCreating" Where="AcctNo == @AcctNo"
ContextTypeName="MyProject.Models.DB_DataDataContext" EnableDelete="True" EnableInsert="True" 
EnableUpdate="True" TableName="Tbl_Addresses" OrderBy="AddressId">
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="1" Name="AcctNo" QueryStringField="AcctNo" Type="Int32" />
    </WhereParameters>
</asp:LinqDataSource>
```

I set the WhereParamater value in the page_load method

Every time the update link is pressed after data is changed I receive an error stating "A critical error has occurred. Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation." or "Cannot access a disposed object"

When the grid view is reload fresh, the data is updated. Nothing I do seems to make a difference. Does anyone have any ideas on why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: THIS code did not post for some reason
 <asp:GridView ID="data_basic_addresses" runat="server" AllowPaging="False"  DataKeyNames="AddressId" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
 DataSourceID="LinqAddressDS"><Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City"  />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="State" HeaderText="State" SortExpression="State"  />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Zip" HeaderText="Zip" SortExpression="Zip"  />
    <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Options" ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
 </Columns></asp:GridView>

Comment: It didn't show because you needed to indent it.  Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fix for the problem

I was trying to pass my own instance of the model connection to be used in a `LinqDS_ContextCreating` method. This worked for all functionality except the Update command. I went in and updated the models default connection string in the `model.designer.cs` file and now the update works.